Encoding with Firefox / google chrome
On my website, I’m using Font Awesome for icons. However, instead of displaying the correct icons, I’m seeing placeholders like squares or empty rectangles (e.g.,  instead of ). This issue persists across different browsers like Google Chrome and Firefox.
When I inspect the website in Firefox, and search for “font-awesome” in the Network tab, I see a similar problem with broken icons (). Despite using the UTF-8 charset, the issue remains unresolved.
What I’ve Tried So Far
•   Browsers: Tested on both Google Chrome and Firefox—same issue.
•   Encoding: Ensured the site uses UTF-8 charset, but no effect.

Possible Causes & Solutions?
Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening, and how to resolve it?
Let me know if you’d like to add more details or include specific steps you’ve tried!

Fixed, Cloudfare added a zstd content type instead of my initial utf-8
